# Media Queries Feature section doesn't show full width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create this media query so that when you open it on a mobile device it has the 3 ".feature-box"'s one on top of the other at full width, however it does not work they just stay as full width? Any idea how to fix this? Code below

HTML

```
  <section>
            <div class="section-header">
                <h2>Services</h2>
                <p>I provide, clean responsive modern websites for you or your business.</p>
            </div>
                <div class="feature-box">
                    <img src="devices.svg" alt="">
                    <h3>Responsive</h3>
                    <p>Works well on any device.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-box">
                    <img src="code.svg" alt="">
                    <h3>Clean Code</h3>
                    <p>Effieciently typed and easy to read.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-box">
                    <img src="clock.svg" alt="">
                    <h3>Fast Loading</h3>
                    <p>Loads fast to ensure your customers stay.</p>
                </div>

        </section>
```

CSS

```
/* Site Section */
section {
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%; }
  section .section-header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0; }
    section .section-header h2 {
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #3F464D; }
  section .feature-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center; }
    section .feature-box img {
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0 0 12px 0;
      line-height: 1; }
    section .feature-box p {
      font-size: 1.5rem; }
```

Media Query

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {

  /* Features */
  .feature-box {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; } }
```

Comment: Do you have something like this in the `<head>` section of your html? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Comment: You are testing this on an actual mobile device?

Comment: Oh, maybe use max-width instead of max-device-width?

Comment: Yes tested on an actual mobile device @conordarcy and yeah I have this in the head tag     <meta name='viewport' width='device-width, initial-scale=1'>

Comment: @RobMoll see other comment

Comment: Regarding my first comment: Are you missing the `content="..."` portion?

Comment: @RobMoll So I have edited the meta name as it turns out I had written width="..." instead of content="..." This fixed the proble, overlooked such a simple fix must have been typing fast

Comment: I added an answer. And for what it's worth, @conordarcy's answer is correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {

  /* Features */
  section .feature-box {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; } }
```

Your selector inside your media query is the problem.
Its should be at least equal specificity so you need the 'section'.

```
section .feature-box{ width: 33% }
```

is more specific than:

```
.feature-box{ width: 100% }
```

and its overriding it.

Comment: So I changed it to section .feature-box and it still hasn't changed

Comment: Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/conor-darcy/pen/MWwJEvJ
I had to change the max media query value but you can change it back.

Comment: You should also look at your image width. If you want it responsive maybe it should be a relative value like percentage also.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/

> First, as with getting all websites to become responsive and adhere to media queries, the viewport meta tag must be placed in the `<head>` section of your web page. The basic standard version of this is shown below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
Once we have this snippet of code in our webpage, if we view the page with different devices, the different media queries will be able to have the correct effect.
```